# Google Adsense JavaScript and IIS 7

Tags: javascript, iis-7, adsense

I'm switching from a LAMP setup to a WIMP setup and everything went fine except my Google Adsense.  When I create a document called adsense.html with the code shown below, it loads properly on my Linux server and shows nothing on my Windows server.  The page source for both pages are identical which has me really confused.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "*******";
/* Banner */
google_ad_slot = "*********";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Additionally when I browse the page from the Windows server itself (localhost/adsense.html) the Adsense ad displays perfectly fine.  When I navigate to it externally, nothing displays.  I've googled this for 2 hours trying everything I can think of.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I know nothing about IIS, but if your page works fine when viewed on localhost, it can't be anything wrong with the page. And seeing as the request is for a URL which is hosted by Google rather than your server, it doesn't seem that your server could be to blame. Is there a chance that your Windows web browser is running ad-blocking or script-blocking software which is allowing localhost to run the AdSense script, but denying your public web domain to run scripts?